# PyQt5: Transparent window with key control

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to create a simple GUI application based on the PyQT5 library. It represents a transparent window, that is always on top, invisible to mouse clicks and the majority of key clicks but still catches some specific keys (say, 'Q' to exit).

The issue is that the keyboard clicks are not visible.

Here's the code.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

DR = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

class QtWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        screen = DR.primaryScreen()
        size = screen.size()
        w = size.width()
        h = size.height()

        self.resize(w, h)
        self.setWindowTitle('Custom Example')
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint |
                            QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                            QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
        self.showMaximized()

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q:
            self.close()

win = QtWindow()
sys.exit(DR.exec_())
```

Is it possible to be achieved here. and how, if it is?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt this would be easily possible with Qt alone: the `WA_TransparentForMouseEvents` may be an obstacle, preventing proper focus grabbing. You should also call `activateWindow()` (as the documentation explicitly says about `X11BypassWindowManagerHint`) but that may still not enough, and, most importantly, if you hope to *only* capture some keys and let any other key be normally managed by the window manager, you're out of luck: as long as a key event is captured by a Qt widget, it's "lost". If you're on Linux, you may consider the pynput library.

Comment: Well, it is enough for me. Ok, thanks.